Is there a standard function to do this? the bind_front and then make vs with 0;
I'm working with C++20's ranges and trying to make my code more concise. Specifically, I have the following code using std::bind_front to check if all values in a std::map<int, int> are equal to 0:
return ranges::all_of(views::values(m), std::bind_front(std::ranges::equal_to(), 0));

While this works, I want to make the code even more compact. I know I can achieve the same result using a lambda or by creating a function overload, but I would like to avoid those approaches. I'm looking for a solution that shortens the code without introducing a lambda or additional function overloads.
Is there a way to directly shorten the code, possibly using std::apply or other C++20 features, without resorting to lambdas or function overloading?

return ranges::all_of(views::values(m), [](int n) { return n == 0; }); is shorter, you might create a functor for equal_to<0> if you want

why do you want to shorten it but without using lambdas or function overloading. Your requirements seem arbitrary (or is this for code golf?)

The standard doesn't have these, but I've seen a few libraries include common utilities for this purpose like eq(0)

Is it that hard to create your own utilities? auto my_eq=[](auto x){return std::bind_front(std::equal_to<>{}, 0);};

@Red.Wave I suspect you wanted another x there.

@Drew.Dormann it is that hard :D

@463035818_is_not_an_ai  :D   I am so guilty of the same.  "This is very simple", I say, holding up my own mistake.

Use abstraction.  Write a function named all_map_values_equal_to or something similar and thdn use it like return all_map_values_equal_to(my_map, my_value); then the guts of the function can be whatever does the job.

@DrewDormann . A typo.

everyone i am sorry i meet trouble again.. and is a big trouble.. can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79248247/i-meet-a-bug-about-stdviewsadjacent-transform-so-i-want-figure-it-out

all_of and other algorithms can already convert an int to a bool. The predicate to use is std::identity:
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

bool no_non_zero_value(const auto& m){
    return !std::ranges::any_of(
        std::views::values(m), 
        std::identity{});
}

int main() {
    std::map<int,int> m1 {{1,0},{2,0}};
    std::cout << no_non_zero_value(m1);
    std::map<int,int> m2 {{1,1},{2,2}};
    std::cout << no_non_zero_value(m2);
    std::map<int,int> m3 {{1,0},{2,2}};
    std::cout << no_non_zero_value(m3);    
}

Output:
100

Note that I swapped all_of for !any_of to see if there is not any non-zero value. Alternatively you can stay with all_of and negate the values via std::logical_not (credits to Drew Dormann):
return std::ranges::all_of(
    std::views::values(m), 
    std::logical_not<void>{});

Live Demo

That's clever.  The "is not zero" predicate is std::identity.  I suppose all_of could also be used with std::logical_not<void>{}.  (Feel free to copy)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79315542/how-can-i-use-stdstring-view-safely      Brother, I'm sorry to bother you again. I  ensure that this question is not a bad question and has a certain degree of difficulty.can you help me..

Bro, I'm really stumped this time.
