Is it safe to pass a temporary std::string to a function accepting std::string_view?
I am working on a C++ program and have a question about the safety of passing a std::string to a function that accepts a std::string_view. Here is my code:
i make some
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void foo(string_view sv) {
    
}

int main() {
    foo(string("abc"));//is it safe?
    return 0;
}

In this example, I am creating a temporary std::string object and passing it to the foo function, which takes a std::string_view as a parameter. I understand that std::string_view is a non-owning reference to a string.
And here is another problem about a leetcode problem.
#include<ranges>

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> smallestTrimmedNumbers(vector<string> &nums, vector<vector<int> > &queries) {
        vector<int> ans;
        auto cmp = [&](auto &a, auto &b) {
            if (a.first == b.first) return a.second < b.second;
            return a.first < b.first;
        };
        for (auto &&q: queries) {
            int k = q[0], t = q[1];
            vector<pair<string_view, int> > p;
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
                p.push_back(make_pair(string_view(nums[i]).substr(nums[i].size() - t), i));
            }
            ranges::nth_element(p, p.begin() + k - 1, cmp);
            ans.push_back(p[k - 1].second);
        }
        return ans;
    }
};

p.push_back(make_pair(string_view(nums[i]).substr(nums[i].size() - t), i));

A string_view is created from nums[i] using string_view(nums[i]), and then substr(nums[i].size() - t) is used to extract the last t characters. Why is string_view(nums[i]) necessary? Couldn’t we just call substr directly on nums[i] without creating a string_view?
My question is:
Is it safe to pass a temporary std::string to a function that takes a std::string_view? Will the lifetime of the temporary std::string be extended for the duration of the function call, or is there a potential for undefined behavior?
I would appreciate a detailed explanation of how std::string_view interacts with temporary objects, and any best practices to avoid potential issues.

The code is safe.

Temporary are destroyed at end of full expression (there are some extension which extend lifetime, it is not the case here).

Temporary_object_lifetime for details.

I think i know something about it, and  i also have a problem with it, may be that is a another problem.

Side notes: (1) #include <bits/stdc++.h> (2) using namespace std.

@Jarod42 Hey bro I made sure to update the question last. I just missed it.
I wonder why I have to convert nums[i] to string_views for it to work properly here. this is leetcode 2343,but i think is not important..

i think (nums[i]).substr(nums[i].size() - t) in this way will work at first, but is wrong. so i add a Obvious cast, maybe the problem not here,i do not know..... c++ is so difficult...

nums[i] is string and string.substr returns a temporary string, whereas converting it to a string_view first calls string_view.substr which returns another string_view to the original string. As for the lifetime extension. Any temporary is destroyed when you hit a semicolon. when storing the string_views in a vector,  You have to make sure they are not bound to temporaries because the temporaries don't live long enough, and you have to make sure the original vector of strings lives long enough, a string_view is like a raw pointer. It can point to dangling strings, you must make sure they don't

You should not store non-owning views (if you are not guarantee of lifetime). nums[i] lifetime is longer than the function scope, nums[i]).substr(..) creates a temporary which ends at the end of full expression, and so should not be stored (in std::vector).

You might want to watch this CppCon 2018: Victor Ciura “Enough string_view to Hang Ourselves”. It often helps too look for CppCon (or CppNorth) videos on topics that interest you :)

c++ is so difficult Yes.  C++ is the most difficult — yet very popular — programming language I have ever worked with with.  And I have worked with several dozen programming langauges over the last 50 years. C++ gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.

Yes. But returning it as string_view is not. Consider string_view as string const&. Similar semantics apply.


Is this code safe?

It depends.
Specifically, it depends on what foo does.  If foo retains a copy/reference to sv or to any of the characters referenced by sv, then that would not be safe.
Example code (untested)
string_view global_sv;

void foo(std::string_view sv) {
    global_sv = sv;
}

After foo returns, global_sv references a destructed string.
If, on the other hand, foo does not retain any references/copies, then the code is fine, because the string that sv is referencing is not destroyed until the end of the expression (i.e, after foo has returned)
void foo(std::string_view sv) {
    std::cout << sv << std::endl;
}


Note that if sv was a const std::string & instead of a std::string_view, this answer would be the same.
